# Modify foreach loop at runtime

Tags: php, foreach

I need to modify looping of foreach loop while its running.

```
$array = array('a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30);
foreach($array as $key => $value) 
{
    echo $value. " ";
    if($key == 'b')
        $array['d'] = 40;
}
print_r($array);
```

I get output like `10 20 30` but, I want that to `10 20 30 40`

Array was modify inside the loop perfectly and giving result `Array ( [a] => 10 [b] => 20 [c] => 30 [d] => 40 )`

Problem is foreach can't loop added element.

Comment: Do you just want to add this d => 40? Or can it be more elements?

Comment: modifying the thing you're looping on WITHIN the loop is always a risky operation...

Comment: @ObjectManipulator also for more elements.

Comment: `$array = array('a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30);
$yieldarray = function () use (&$array){
    while(next($array)){
        list($k,$v)=each($array);
        yield $k=>$v;
    }
};
$yieldarray = $yieldarray();
foreach($yieldarray as $key => $value) 
{
    echo $value. " ";
    if($key == 'b')
        $array['d'] = 40;
}
print_r($array);`

Comment: @GuRu That would do the trick, in PHP7. But do it not! :))

Comment: Little bug change the while like `while($next=each($array)){
        list($k,$v)=$next;
        yield $k=>$v;
    }`

Comment: Perfect answer @JustOnUnderMillions thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome in the world of PHP 7 ;)